# JavaScript curry function

Tags: javascript, partial-application

I have implemented a `curry` function this way:

```
function curry (fn) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
    return function () {
        fn.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
    };
}
```

When I use the above function to do the following

```
function add (x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

var inc = curry(add, 1);
console.log(inc(10));
```

it logs `undefined`. Isn't 11 the expected output? What is wrong with my code?

Note: Using `console.log(x, y)` inside the `add` function logs `1 10`. I don't understand why it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Actually is not curry, it's partial application.

Comment: I know I'm reviving a really old thread, but what does applying `[1]` as the argument to `arguments` accomplish?

Comment: It removes the passed function from the arguments list!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in your curry function.

I.e.

```
return function () {
    return fn.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
};
```

That seems to work :)

Comment: the correct term for this is partial application of a function - not strictly currying...but still good!

Answer (score 12):

This is an example of curry function:

```
function curry(func) {
    var initial_args = [].slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
    var func_args_length = func.length;

    function curried(args) {
        if (args.length >= func_args_length) {
            return func.apply(null, args);
        }

        return function () {
            return curried(args.concat([].slice.apply(arguments)));
        };
    }

    return curried(initial_args);
}
```

This curry function creates a curried version of any function. You can partially apply parameters to the new function. For each partial application, it will return a function that takes the rest of the parameters. Once all parameters of the original function are applied, it will return a value.