# Currying Javascript function with custom order of fixed parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, partial-application

Currying functions can be usefull:

```
function tag(name, value) {  
    return '<' + name + '>' + value + '</' + name + '>';
}

var strong = tag.bind(undefined, "strong");
strong("text"); // <strong>text</strong>
```

Now imagine we have to use another function with wrong order of parameters

```
function otherTag(value, name) {  
    return '<' + name + '>' + value + '</' + name + '>';
}
```

How to use bind function to get the same result - create strong tag using otherTag function.

How to curry this function using **bind** only?

---

I'm not interested in solution based on wrapping the otherTag function like this:

```
wrapOtherTag(name, value) {
    return otherTag(value, name);
}
```

What I want to know if it is possible to pass arguments to bind to tell the order of arguments we want to curry.

Comment: Nope. Arguments are bound in the order you pass them. You'd have to implement your own solution.

Comment: @opengrid. You may get more interest if you detail a situation where this might be useful.

Comment: @opengrid. P.S. Are you sure `currying` is the correct term for what you're asking?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this.  You want to reverse the order of arguments, but you want bind to magically know what order you want them to be in?  Why not use an object: `{name:name, value:value}` in that case?

Comment: The Functional.js library has a function that lets you do this, though it's mostly useful as an academic example.

Comment: @flem: Yes it is :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/36321

Comment: I like Functional.js solution. so bind is only for simple cases.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394747/javascript-curry-function?rq=1) shows a way to do currying in js.

Comment: @LeeMeador I think bind is more concise way to curry a function unless you want do things that only rcurry or partial can do.

Comment: @opengrid, `.bind` is *based* on that implementation of currying. It's native, now, for modern browsers, but that is how shims and libraries *make* their `.bind` functions to begin with.  The point of `.binding` is to return the exact-same function, in the exact-same order, with an encapsulated value for `this`. Currying from there is a matter of popping arguments off the stack and returning half-created functions which use cached versions of those arguments.  You can build complex versions of that, you can build a function which inverts the order, you can use configuration objects, not bind.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to reverse argument order:

```
function swap(fn) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return fn(b, a); 
    };
}
```

Now just call

```
swap(otherTag).bind(0, "strong");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to accomplish this.

```
// Uncurry `this` in `slice`.
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

function curry(fn, arg, index) {
    return function curried(/* ...args */) {
        var args = slice(arguments);
        args.splice(index, 0, arg);
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
}

var strong = curry(tag, "strong", 0);
strong("text"); // <strong>text</strong>

var otherStrong = curry(otherTag, "strong", 1);
otherStrong("text"); // <strong>text</strong>
```