# Unable to write add method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to write an `add` function so that we can call it as

```
add(3,5);
// and 
add(3)(5);
```

in JavaScript?

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?

Comment: Are we supposed to do it for you or can you share your code and what it isn't doing?

Comment: This looks a lot like _currying_, JavaScript can certainly do currying.

Comment: Can you please help me in writing this

Comment: you want to be able to call it as `add(3)(5)`? That's not normal syntax for JavaScript (although it would be possible if you abused your add function to return a function... still weird though, and would be very difficult for code writers to understand). Stick to normal syntax and your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: provide some more information...what you are trying to do?... what is not working...

Comment: To clarify, you want to be able to call it as `add(3,5)` or as `add(3)(5)` ?  A function that can do both?  Or just `add(3)(5)`?

Comment: Woww....Thanks Halcyon for that word "currying". I got it. Can you explain bit about what is currying in javascript?

Comment: To answer your question, just write `var add = function () {};` and you're done. So maybe you should put a little more detail into your question, and we can put a little detail more in the answers :)

Comment: Is that you're asking for? http://jsfiddle.net/vmsy6dvk/

Comment: Yes.. I want to call it as add(3,5) and add(3)(5). Both should work and it should return the sum.

Comment: Exactly SiZiOUS. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution based on my original comment. By the way I see that everyone there had the same idea (returning a `function` object.).

```
var add = (function(x, z) {
    return (typeof(z) !== "undefined") ? x + z : function(y) { return x + y; }
});

var value = add(3)(5);
alert(value); // 8

value = add(3, 5);
alert(value); // 8
```

If the original goal of your question was about *currying*, I found a document interesting about that, using JavaScript : https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic way to curry **any** function as long as it has all its formal parameters defined (i.e. it doesn't work with variadic functions).

```
function curry(f) {
    return function() {
        if (arguments.length >= f.length) {
            return f.apply(null, arguments);
        }
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        return curry(f.bind.apply(f,[null].concat(args)));
    }
}
```

It works by comparing the number of parameters the function accepts (exposed via the [`.length` property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.1)) to the number of arguments passed to the function. If less arguments are passed to the function than it accepts, it returns a new function with bound parameters.

Usage:

```
function add(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

add = curry(add);

console.log(add(1,1,1));   // 3
console.log(add(1,1));     // function
console.log(add(1,1)(2));  // 4
console.log(add(1)(2,2));  // 5
console.log(add(1)(2)(3)); // 6
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/90zs4n92/

---

An alternative implementation which avoids binding arguments can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045565/218196).

Comment: Really brilliant! This approach is really smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
function addFactory(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  };
}

//Make an addingFunction
var addThree = addFactory(3);

addThree(5);  // returns 8

//Or, in short
addFactory(3)(5);  // returns 8
```

You could probably make the function handle both the `add(3,5)` case and the `add(3)(5)` case by checking `arguments.length` and the type of the arguments.  However, I would imagine it would be easier and more readable just to have 2 functions with an if statement.  Not sure what you're using it for.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with either way:

```
add = function(a, b) {
    if(b === undefined) {
        return function(b) {
            return add(a, b);
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}
alert(add(3)(5));
alert(add(3, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a curryable function - a function that takes *n* amount of arguments, but if you call it without all the arguments, it returns a partially applied function.

```
var add = function(a, b) {
    if(arguments.length === 2) {
        return a + b;
    }
    else {
        return function(x) { return x + a }
    }
}

var addFour = add(4); 

add(4, 3); // => 7
add(4)(3); // => 7
addFour(3); // => 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function add() {
   //Check the number of arguments
   var argLength = arguments.length;

   //No arguments
   if(argLength == 0) {
      return null;
   }

   //Only one argument, then return another function. 
   if(argLength == 1) {
      var first = arguments[0];
      return function(second) {
         return first + second;
      }
   }

   //More than one argument, then add them all.
   var output = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < argLength; i++) {
      output += arguments[i];
   }
   return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
   function add(a, b) {
    if(b === undefined || arguments.length !== 2) {
        return function(b) {
            return add(a, b);
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}
alert(add(3)(5));
alert(add(3, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currying is when you break down a function that takes multiple arguments into a series of functions that take part of the arguments. Here's an example in Scheme

```
(define (add a b)
(+ a b))

(add 3 4) returns 7
```

This is a function that takes two arguments, a and b, and returns their sum. We will now curry this function:

```
(define (add a)
    (lambda (b)
        (+ a b)))`
```

This is a function that takes one argument, a, and returns a function that takes another argument, b, and that function returns their sum.

```
((add 3) 4)

(define add3 (add 3))

(add3 4)
```

The first statement returns 7, like the (add 3 4) statement. The second statement defines a new function called add3 that will add 3 to its argument. This is what some people may call a closure. The third statement uses the add3 operation to add 3 to 4, again producing 7 as a result.