# Closure and chaining a function call in JS - how to check last call?

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

I have a JavaScript function with unlimited arguments that also has an inside function that uses this arguments. Something like the function in this [StackOveflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984719/can-i-write-an-infinitely-curried-function) which is

```
function StringCon(arg) {
    var f = function(x) {
        return StringCon(arg + x);
    };
    // var f = StringCon.bind(this, arg + x);

    f.value = arg;

    return f;
}

StringCon("I ")("am ")("new ")("to")(" JavaScript")
.value // -> "I am new to JavaScript"
```

I actually want to check where does this infinite currying ends. In the above example, I want to check when I get to the last call ("Javascript").

Actually I want to use this check in order to not use `.value` . I actually want to use `StringCon("I ")("am ")("new ")("to")(" JavaScript")` to get the "I am new to JavaScript" String itself, not a function which contains an attribute named value. So a I can actually use `StringCon("HI)("HI") + StringCon("BYE")("BYE")`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, it’s impossible.

Comment: I think slebetman’s answer in the linked question is pretty applicable. Note: the implicit versions where you override `valueOf` or `toString` are not good design.